# Python-like .format() in php

Tags: php, python, regex, language-comparisons

I have the following array:

```
$matches[0] = "123";
$matches[1] = "987";
$matches[2] = "121";
```

And the following string:

```
$result = "My phone number is {0} and police number is {2}";
```

I would like to replace the `{}` placeholder based on the `$matches` array, in case there is no match for placeholder display nothing instead.

What is the best way to achieve that, or do you know a better solution to my problem?

(Right now I am building the system, so instead of curly brackets I could use any other symbol)

## UPDATE

In python this is possible using `.format()` function.

Comment: `str_replace()` doesn't it work

Comment: There's `vsprintf`.

Comment: Using `printf` i am forced to make the array in order, can I select using array indexes?

Comment: You could do a string replace in a while loop find '{' + i + '}' replace with array[ i ]

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte could you show me an example n how I could use vsprintf ?

Comment: @sln you are right, however I am searching for a function

Comment: See http://ideone.com/S12EXd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it with `vsprintf`, you don't have to change the order of items if you give the number (from 1) of your item like this: `%n$s` (where n is the number):

```
$matches = [ "123", "987", "121"];
$result = 'My phone number is %1$s and police number is %3$s';

$res = vsprintf($result, $matches);
```

Note that you have to put the formatted string between single quotes, otherwise `$s` will be interpreted as a variable and replaced with nothing.

*(`vprintf` and `vsprintf` are designed for arrays, but you can do the same thing with `printf` and `sprintf` for separated variables, it works the same)*

---

If you can't change your original Python formatted string, the way is to use `preg_replace_callback`:

```
$matches = [ "123", "987", "121"];
$result = 'My phone number is {0} and police number is {2}';

$res = preg_replace_callback('~{(\d+)}~', function ($m) use ($matches) {
    return isset($matches[$m[1]]) ? $matches[$m[1]] : $m[0];
}, $result);
```

or you can build an associative array where the keys are placeholders and values your array values, and use `strtr` for the replacement:

```
$matches = [ "123", "987", "121"];
$result = 'My phone number is {0} and police number is {2}';

$trans = array_combine(
    array_map(function ($i) { return '{'.$i.'}'; }, array_keys($matches)),
    $matches
);

$result = strtr($result, $trans);
```

Comment: The code here: ideone.com/S12EXd is also nice. Thank you very much, will accept is as the correct answer, is very clean.

Comment: Mail merge makes a comeback.

Comment: @PHPLover: your example doesn't work since it depends of the order of placeholders.

Comment: @sln: I have never used Mail merge, but formatted strings are indeed an old technology since it comes from C language. Note that the old way to make formatted strings in Python is very similar.